# ag grid vue grouping set columns expanded after component reload

Tags: vue.js, save, grouping, ag-grid, expand

I use ag-grid table - I am grouping the columns e.g. like:
[image]

Is it possible to set columns expanded the same way they were after components reload?
How to save how columns were expanded and then reload it?

Answer (score -1):

One way is to store the ids of the nodes which are expanded (I do so in local storage as there aren't many rows in my table and I know I won't store anything confidential).  Then on reload, retrieve the nodes that should be expanded and expand them:

```
<ag-grid-angular
  (rowGroupOpened)="onRowGroupOpened()"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```

```
localStorageKey = 'storage-key-name';

onRowGroupOpened(): void {
    let allExpanded = true;
    const expandedNodeDetails: string[] = [];
    if (this.myGrid.gridApi != null) {
      this.myGrid.gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
        if (node.group || (node.allChildrenCount > 0)) {
          if (!this.restoringExpandedNodes) {
            expandedNodeDetails.push(node.key);
          }
        }
      });
    }

    if (!this.restoringExpandedNodes) {
      localStorage.setItem(this.localStorageKey, JSON.stringify(expandedNodeDetails));
    }
  }

onGridReady(): void {
    this.restoreExpandedNodes();  
  }

restoreExpandedNodes(): void {
    const itemsInStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.localStorageKey));
    if ((itemsInStorage != null) && (this.myGrid != null) && (this.myGrid.gridApi != null)) {
      this.restoringExpandedNodes = true;
      this.myGrid.gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
        if (node.group || (node.allChildrenCount > 0)) {
          const expandedDetails = this.getExpandedDetails(node, null);
          const index = itemsInStorage.findIndex(storageItem => storageItem === expandedDetails);
          if (index !== -1) {
            node.expanded = true;
          } else if ((itemToSelect != null) && (node.key == itemToSelect.ItemFullName)) {
            node.expanded = true;
          }
        }
      });

      this.myGrid.gridApi.onGroupExpandedOrCollapsed();
      this.restoringExpandedNodes = false;
    }
  }
```

I've had to sanitise this code so please let me know if something doesn't make sense

Comment: Downvoter - I'd be grateful for feedback so I can improve my answer